# why do user defined types in zig need to be const?

Tags: zig

In case I need to declare a struct in Zig I have to prefix it with a `const`

```
const Arith = struct {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,

    fn add(self: *Arith) i32 {
        return self.x + self.y;
    }
};

test "struct test" {
    var testArith = Arith{
        .x = 9,
        .y = 9,
    };

    expect(testArith.add() == 18);
}
```

But it can be initialized both ways as `var` and `const` so why does the type declaration need a constant keyword when it only matters whether the instance of the struct is `const` or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to be `const` because the order of evaluation in the root scope is undefined and because the variables of type `type` only can live in the compiler (has no memory representation, the compiler is unable to produce a binary representation of it). But you can use `var` inside other scopes:

```
comptime {
   var T = struct { value: u64 };
   
   const x: T = .{ .value = 3 };

   T = struct { ok: bool };

   const y: T = .{ .ok = true };

   @compileLog(x.value); // <- 3
   @compileLog(y.ok); // <- true
}
```

[Run this code](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:zig,selection:(endColumn:19,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:19,positionLineNumber:6,selectionStartColumn:19,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:19,startLineNumber:6),source:%27comptime+%7B%0A+++var+T+%3D+struct+%7B+value:+u64+%7D%3B%0A+++%0A+++const+x:+T+%3D+.%7B+.value+%3D+3+%7D%3B%0A%0A+++T+%3D+struct+%7B+ok:+bool+%7D%3B%0A%0A+++const+y:+T+%3D+.%7B+.ok+%3D+true+%7D%3B%0A%0A+++@compileLog(x.value)%3B+//+%3C-+3%0A+++@compileLog(y.ok)%3B+//+%3C-+true%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Zig+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:44.03116088656192,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:ztrunk,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:zig,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27zig+trunk+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+Zig%27,t:%270%27)),k:19.895173765628456,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+zig+trunk%27,t:%270%27)),k:36.073665347809595,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

In the rest of the answer, I explain in detail.

## Const

```
const Arith = struct {...};
```

Creates a constant variable of a inferred type. In this case, the variable `Arith` has type `type`:

```
const Arith = struct {...};
comptime {
   @compileLog(@TypeOf(Arith)); // <- type
}
```

[Run this code](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:zig,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:14),source:%27const+Arith+%3D+struct+%7B%0A++++x:+i32,%0A++++y:+i32,%0A%0A++++fn+add(self:+*Arith)+i32+%7B%0A++++++++return+self.x+%2B+self.y%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Acomptime+%7B%0A++++@compileLog(@TypeOf(Arith))%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Zig+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:44.03116088656192,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:ztrunk,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:zig,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27zig+trunk+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+Zig%27,t:%270%27)),k:19.895173765628456,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+zig+trunk%27,t:%270%27)),k:36.073665347809595,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

---

This is the same as declare the variable as:

```
const Arith: type = struct {...};
```

---

## Var

You also can create a variable with `var`

**Examples:**

```
comptime {
   var Arith = struct {...};
}
```

```
comptime {
   var Arith: type = struct {...};
}
```

```
fn main() !void {
   comptime var Arith = struct {...};
}
```

```
fn main() !void {
   var Arith: type = struct {...};
}
```

```
fn main() !void {
   comptime var Arith: type = struct {...};
}
```

---

Because is a variable you can modify it:

```
comptime {
   var T = u64;
   T = bool;
   @compileLog(T); // <-- bool
}
```

[Run this code](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:zig,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:5,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:5,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:5,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:5),source:%27comptime+%7B%0A+++var+T+%3D+u64%3B%0A+++T+%3D+bool%3B%0A+++@compileLog(T)%3B+//+%3C--+bool%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Zig+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:44.03116088656192,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:ztrunk,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:zig,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27zig+trunk+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+Zig%27,t:%270%27)),k:19.895173765628456,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+zig+trunk%27,t:%270%27)),k:36.073665347809595,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

---

## Comptime Types

There is types that can only live in the compiler, like: `type` or structs that have a field of type `anytype` or other comptime type.

In the case of `type`, this make the compiler interpret `var x: type` as `comptime var x: type`.

Then, consider the following code:

```
var T = struct { value: u64 }; // <- Compiler error

comptime {
   const x: T = .{ .value = 3 };
}
```

```
error: variable of type 'type' must be constant
```

because the order of evaluation in the root scope is undefined, the compiler forces to create a global variable inside the binary, but the type `type` has no memory representation. So, the compiler raises an error.

Comment: this is a very good answer, much better than my understanding of it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Arith` is of the type `type` it has to be declared a constant because the compiler expects it to be. This can be checked by changing the type declaration to this and running the program

```
var Arith = struct {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,

    fn add(self: *Arith) i32 {
        return self.x + self.y;
    }
};
```

which will result in the error  `error: variable of type 'type' must be constant`

Also in Zig we need either a `const` or a `var` preceeding a name otherwise it is considered an invalid token.